# How to get ID comment reply with same ID, same class with Parent Comment ID (Using Selenium scraper data)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a structure:

```
[
 # If it is a comment (parent comment)
 {
  'commentParentId': '',
  'parentId': '',
  'posted': '28/02/2019',
  'author': {
     'id': '125379',
     'name': 'david',
  },
  'content': 'i need help'
 },
 # If it is a comment reply
 {
  'commentParentId': 'abcdedf',
  'parentId': '253654',
  'posted': '28/02/2019',
  'author': {
    'id': '458216',
    'name': 'david',
  },
  'content': 'i need help'
  },
  ........................
  }]
```

I want to **scrape** comment and comment replies,

If it is a comment: `CommentParentID`and `ParentID` are `null`.

Else, it is a comment reply: `CommentParentID` and `ParentID` will take `ID` from comment which someone replied.

I am **scraping** comments using Selenium, like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver

# Execute Web link
url = "https://genvita.vn/thu-thach/7-ngay-detox-da-dep-dang-thon-nguoi- 
       khoe-qua-soc-len-den-8-trieu-dong"
driver_path = ('F:/chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
browser.get(url)

confirm_write = input("Input ok to scrape data: ")
# I want to load all comments (click 'Xem Thêm' then data was 
# scraper)

if confirm_write == 'ok':

getID = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='media-body- 
         replies']")
getChildID = getID.find_elements_by_css_selector('data-comment-id')
# Get ID
for childID in getChildID:
    print(childID.get_attribute('data-comment-id'))
```

But my code is not working.

Comment and comment reply have same class, same id, just difference is between comment and comment reply is the class : `class ='media-body-replies'`.

But I am using this and it is not working.

If I use `getChildID = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('data-comment-id')`

I will get all ID's of `parentID` and `replyID` (similar with content), I cannot separate between comment and comment reply.

Thank You

Comment: Something is not clear to me. When you use "data-comment-id" you get both types of comments, but you only want one of them or you want to be able to seperate parent and child comments?

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock i want to seperate parent and child comments, because ID and class of parent and child comments are the same, It has no difference except child comments inside class `class='media-body-replies'`, i will try it but it cannot scrap child comments.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock you can access my website : https://genvita.vn/thu-thach/7-ngay-detox-da-dep-dang-thon-nguoi-khoe-qua-soc-len-den-8-trieu-dong for get more information data was scraper

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to search for the comments container and looping through the comments while looking at the type of comment?

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock I was tried but it not working, because ID and class of parent and child comments it not difference, so I cann't create a loop to seperate and search parent and child comments

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock I can only scraper parent and child comments, cann't seperate and save data in my structure (in the post head)